# Why is my API working with Postman but not working with Java Get request

Tags: java, rest, exception, rest-assured

The data successfully appears when executing from Postman but when execute a script from JAVA I get

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7$1 (file:/C:/Users/****/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/2.5.8/groovy-2.5.8.jar) to constructor java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup(java.lang.Class,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release

java.net.UnknownHostException: No such host is known (ar****-test****)
```

Code:

```
String token = "eyJh******";
Response response = given().headers("Authorization", "Bearer " + token, "Content-Type", ContentType.JSON, "Accept", ContentType.JSON)
    .when()
    .get("https://ar*****-test.*******")
    .then()
    .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
    .extract()
    .response();
```

The data from Postman received in JSON format.

Comment: Is this running on the same machine as postman?

Comment: Yes, the same machine

Comment: Typo error? Try to ping the host name. If you have a response try to replace the host name by IP address (not as a solution but just to get hints on the issue).