# Rest api is returning bad request using VSCode or postman while it is working with my android app?

Tags: java, android, rest, visual-studio-code, postman

My problem is opposite of most of problems that have been posted in web like
[Why is my API working with Postman but not working with Java Get request](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59790817/21193451) or [HttpClient returning Bad Request while Postman is working fine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42758443/21193451)

My rest API is working very well on my java android app but it fail to login using Thunder Client VSCode extension or desktop postman running with Xampp. All of these API tools returning `Status: 400 Bad Request` and can't verify even first field of login form while in android app it has no problem.

What has caused this problem?

I am using retrofit2 for my working java codes: (phone = 123456, password = 123456789)

```
@POST("http://localhost/myapp/index.php/auth/login")
    ApiResponse<AuthResponse> login(@Body UserLogin userLogin);
```

and in VSCode

[image]

and this is the my Xampp details:

[image]

Comment: You are probably missing something that your app/retrofit is doing. Why don't you compare the request the app makes with the ones you are making in Postman?

Comment: @KenWolf: How can I compare them? just comparing the links inside of Android Studio LOG? it is same as postman one.

Comment: Different ways: 1) Increase logging client-side (eg via OKhttp logging interceptor) so you can see the full request (headers, etc.). 2) Check on the server side. 3) Use a proxy (fiddler, etc.) to sniff traffic

Comment: Play around with Postman x-wwwform-urlencoded, perhaps your retrofit call is sending that rather than application/json.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @KenWolf: Your two comments answer to my question. Please expand your comments and post an answer to remove this post from unanswered list. (I used `.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY));` for full debug)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app is doing something that you are missing in the Postman call. For example:

- Missing headers
- Fields
- Content formatting

To solve this you'll need to see the full request that your app is making - often default logging is not enough.

There are a few ways to do this:

1. Increase logging client-side (eg via [OKHttp logging interceptor](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor))
2. Check on the server side.
3. Use a proxy (`Fiddler`, `Charles` etc.) to sniff network traffic

I would go with 1) as the simplest. The likelihood is you are missing some headers or similar.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here might be related to the headers of your request.
Make sure you are sending the same headers via Postman/VS Code as the ones used in your Android app